# Separating one dimensional string array into the 2 Dimensional string array

Tags: c#

I need a help can someone please sort me out ?

I have one dimensional array, I want separate it into two dimensional array, by creating two string arrays  the first is  `string[,]` and the other one is empty `string[]` under the two dimensional column.

But I get an error which looks like `WRONG NUMBER OF INDICIES INSIDE EXPECTED 2` in the first `FOR` loop under the `** two dimensional array**`, near the `tofinds[i]`.

Can someone please tell me what would be the issue ?

```
**One dimensional Array**

string[] tofinds = {
    "Scale_NCR_Bag BOOT_FIRMWARE 497-0465768", //0
    "Scale_NCR_Bag MAIN_FIRMWARE 497-0474615",
    "Scale_NCR_Bag SERIAL_NUMBER",

    "Scale_NCR_Bag POD1_SERIAL_NUMBER",
    "Scale_NCR_Bag POD2_SERIAL_NUMBER",
    "Scale_NCR_Bag POD3_SERIAL_NUMBER",
    "Scale_NCR_Bag POD4_SERIAL_NUMBER",

    "Scale_NCR_Bag POD1_MODEL_NUMBER",
    "Scale_NCR_Bag POD2_MODEL_NUMBER",
    "Scale_NCR_Bag POD3_MODEL_NUMBER",
    "Scale_NCR_Bag POD4_MODEL_NUMBER"

};

for (int i = 0; i < tofinds.Length; i++)
{
    if (!System.Linq.Enumerable.Contains(moduleParametersDic.Keys, tofinds[i]))
    {
        throw new TestFailedException(tofinds[i] + " not found in CaddRuntime !");
    }
    else
    {
        testExecutor.WriteToJournal("? " + moduleToFind.ToLower() + "|" + tofinds[i] + 
        "|" + moduleParametersDic[tofinds[i]]);
    }
}


    **Two dimensional Array**

string[,] tofinds = {
    {"BOOT_FIRMWARE", "497-0465768"}, //0
    {"MAIN_FIRMWARE", "497-0474615"},                    
};

string[] tofinds1 = {           
    "SERIAL_NUMBER",    
    "POD1_SERIAL_NUMBER",
    "POD2_SERIAL_NUMBER",
    "POD3_SERIAL_NUMBER",
    "POD4_SERIAL_NUMBER",

    "POD1_MODEL_NUMBER",
    "POD2_MODEL_NUMBER",
    "POD3_MODEL_NUMBER",
    "POD4_MODEL_NUMBER"
    };

for (int i = 0; i < tofinds.Length; i++)
{
    if (!System.Linq.Enumerable.Contains(moduleParametersDic.Keys, tofinds[i]))
    {
        throw new TestFailedException(tofinds[i] + " not found in CaddRuntime !");
    }
    else
    {
        testExecutor.WriteToJournal("? " + moduleToFind.ToLower() + "|" + tofinds[i] + 
        "|" + moduleParametersDic[tofinds[i]]);
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < tofinds1.Length; i++)
{
    if (!System.Linq.Enumerable.Contains(moduleParametersDic.Keys, tofinds1[i]))
    {
        throw new TestFailedException(tofinds1[i] + " not found in CaddRuntime !");
    }
    else
    {
        testExecutor.WriteToJournal("? " + moduleToFind.ToLower() + "|" + tofinds1[i] + 
        "|" + moduleParametersDic[tofinds1[i]]);
    }
}
```

### MODIFIED

Hope this should work right ? The first string array is the two dimensional and the second string array which I'm using is a single dimensional.

For the first `FOR` loop, I have created a multiple for loop `i` & `j`.

```
string[,] tofinds =
{
    { "BOOT_FIRMWARE", "497-0465768"},
    { "MAIN_FIRMWARE", "497-0474615"},                    
};

string[] tofinds1 =
{
    "SERIAL_NUMBER",
    "POD1_SERIAL_NUMBER",
    "POD2_SERIAL_NUMBER",
    "POD3_SERIAL_NUMBER",
    "POD4_SERIAL_NUMBER",
    "POD1_MODEL_NUMBER",
    "POD2_MODEL_NUMBER",
    "POD3_MODEL_NUMBER",
    "POD4_MODEL_NUMBER",
};


    for (int i = 0; i < tofinds.Length; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < tofinds.Length; j++)
    {
        if 
    (!System.Linq.Enumerable.Contains(moduleParametersDic.Keys, 
    tofinds[i,j]))
        {
            throw new TestFailedException(tofinds[i,j] + " not 
        found in CaddRuntime !");
        }
        else
        {
            testExecutor.WriteToJournal("? " + 
            moduleToFind.ToLower() + "|" + tofinds[i,j] + "|" + 
            moduleParametersDic[tofinds[i,j]]);
        }
    }
}


for (int i = 0; i < tofinds.Length; i++)
{                    
        if (!System.Linq.Enumerable.Contains(moduleParametersDic.Keys, tofinds[i]))
        {
            throw new TestFailedException(tofinds[i] + " not found in CaddRuntime !");
        }
        else
        {
            testExecutor.WriteToJournal("? " + moduleToFind.ToLower() + "|" + tofinds[i] + "|" + moduleParametersDic[tofinds[i]]);
        }
    
}
```

Comment: `string[,] tofinds` is a multi-dimensional array and yet you are calling `tofinds[i]` which is only a single index on a multi-dimensional array. at the very least it would need to be `tofinds[i,j]`

Comment: ok so it should be something like tofinds[0,i] ??? Can you please let me know ?

Comment: Depending on your needs, that might work, at least it wouldn't be a compiler error

Comment: ok so will the above one works ? I Added a new row called MODIFIED in the above query.

Comment: @shashank Please, spend some time to properly format your question

Comment: I do not understand what it is you are actually trying to do. Convert between 1D array and 2D? Iterate over a 2D array? Both examples contain errors like not using the correct number of indices the array, and using .Length instead of .GetLength(dimension).

Comment: Are you looking for the serial number as index zero or index one in { "BOOT_FIRMWARE", "497-0465768"}?  The variable j is being used to check first index zero and then index one.  I think the serial number will always be in index one.